# Puppet Jruby NetHttp get request seems to have bad ciphers

Tags: ruby, encryption, puppet, jruby, java

We wrote a puppet function which needs to do a http get request over tls to a server. The http request is done directly from the puppet master. The remote server needs apparently more recents ciphers than provided by our function (we use the ruby  Net/Http library). Consequently, the remote server immedialty close the connection (Client Hello, [ACK], [FIN, ACK] )

```
def http_client
  uri = URI("https://#{@config['server']}")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE unless @config['vmssc_tls_verify']
  http
end
```

We tried to CuRL the same API from the puppet master, with success, it appears the openssl version used by CuRL is different than the one used by puppet.

The difference we found was that in curl we had like 32 ciphers in SHA256 but with the Net/Http library used by puppet we only had 11 ciphers in SHA1.
Puppet server is running with jruby, so we tried to add java cryptography extension in openJDK but without success.
We also observe that the ciphers listed in the /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d/puppetserver.conf file are not honored (hence we got the list of the ciphers used by the client in our tcpdump) :

```
# settings related to HTTP client requests made by Puppet Server
http-client: {
# A list of acceptable protocols for making HTTP requests
ssl-protocols: [
    TLSv1.2,
]

# A list of acceptable cipher suites for making HTTP requests
cipher-suites: [
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
]
```

We tried to upgrade the version of openJDK to an oracle JDK but without success.
We're running on a puppetserver version 2.7.0 with Jruby and openJDK 8 with a TLS_Version 1.2.

Also when the puppetserver is started in native ruby everything works fine, we've got the goods ciphers. We don't want to stay with that configuration for the performance issue.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I asked a similar question on the puppet forums (https://ask.puppet.com/question/33316/puppet-https-connection-using-latest-tls-version-and-cipher-suites/) but had no response

Comment: Hi no i haven't got any response but we've found a solution by doing a call not with the puppet functions but rather doing some curl .

Comment: @DimitriQuenault We are migrating to Puppet-5. And facing problems when of our function attempts to put http get.  The same code works on Puppet3.7.  Do you have any suggestion for to get that resolved?  This is the error we get with Puppet-5. Error while evaluating a Function Call, Received fatal alert: unsupported_certificate (file: /etc/puppet/environments/dbenv1/modules/role_xxxx/manifests/idb.pp, line: 62, column: 7)